# jQuery Deferred objects for a requests in directory tree form

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I want to do AJAX requests to follow a tree like structure, kinda like a file system directory where directories link to other directories. Only in my case I follow a REST API that where I follow IDs. Like with every request I receive a list of IDs of the subdirectories (and "files" in the end).

So what I want to do is to make AJAX calls inside AJAX calls using forEach. I want to check whether an error occurred and I want to make sure that it waits for the requests to complete so that in the end I am able to process and return the data I received. How would I do that?

So I basically have JSON like this and start from /directories. I want to get all the files and return them from a function as one big JSON.

/directories

```
["directoryA", "directoryB"]
```

/direcotry/directoryA

```
["subDirectory1", "subDirectory2"]
```

/direcotry/directoryB

```
["subDirectory4"]
```

/directory/subDirectory1

```
["fileA", "fileB"]
```

/directory/subDirectory2

```
["fileC"]
```

/file/fileA

```
{"some content"}
```

/file/fileB

```
{"Hello world"}
```

/file/fileC

```
{"nickname": "Clown", "id": 9247234}
```

...

My code currently about this (sorry, the original one is CoffeeScript and does lots of other stuff helping to decide what to get and how to sort them in the end):

```
function getFiles(settings){
  $.ajax("/directories", settings, function(directories) {
    data.forEach(function (directory) {
      $ajax("/directory/" + directory, settings, function(subdirectory) {
        // and so on, in the innermost processing the file contents,
        // but unable to return them.
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to clarify your question a bit more, make it very specific and in your sample code that you are using currently.

Comment: Is there always only exactly one level of subdirectories or could be an entire filesystem tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Deferreds or Promises to make a bunch of requests and collect the data in an outer done callback using [`jQuery's $.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Making a bunch of roundtrips for each directory and file might be slow. Being lazier about getting directories and files or having the server get larger chunks of data (like `ls -R`) or combining the requests with something like [ql.io](http://ql.io/) could be faster.